# Copying an Array from a line, into an Array Object - "_numbersArray is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null"

Tags: c#, arrays, class, oop, field

I am creating an application that will read in a CSV file, with 5 x lotto numbers on each line.

For each line, I take the array of lotto numbers (named csvArray in the screenshot), and create a "LottoLine" object.

(The LottoLine object is basically just another array)

As you can see I have created my _numbersArray array, then in the constructor I have looped through each element on the csvfile array, to update the values of _numbersArray.

However my _numbersArray for some reason is not allowing the numbers of the csvfile array to copy across and I am receiving the warning "arrayName is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null"

I'm very new to Object-Oriented Programming so I have tried winging it with:

- creating a get set property for the _numbersArray
- changed the field from public to protected
- adding static to the _numbersArray field
- using the array.copy method

All failures obviously.

Really appreciate any advice on this issue as well as my question format, please let me know if I should elaborate more or provide better context etc.

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) but provide it as text

Comment: You must initialize the array: `numbersArray = new int[arraySize];`

Comment: The compiler is trying to tell you have an error in your code. Indeed the __numbersArray_ is never initialized. At this point it is just a variable declaration of a reference type and its default is _null_. You need to initialize it with _new int[6]_ or just assign the _csvArray_ reference to __numbersArray_ (the one or the other should be choosen knowing better your context)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have created an Array in you example. In C# you need to call the constructor of the array with a fixed size. So your first line inside of the constructor should be something like this:

```
_numbersArray = new int[42]
```

Then you have an error inside your loop. Iterating and accessing elements of an array, without knowing the bounds is dangerous.

In order to make this better you should change your constructor to something like this:

```
_numbersArray = new int[6];
for(int i = 0; i < vcsArray.length && i < _numbersArray.length; i++)
{...
```